# Function domain and range

Tags: functions

I have a function defined as: $ f: \mathbb{N}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with signature $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, no more. I need to do a certain proof. What does the definition mean? For some reason, I thought it was taking a cube root of any natural perfect cube, but that doesn't seem to make sense. I apologize for such a simple question, but this is not mentioned in my CS book.

Comment: $f$ maps triples of natural numbers to natural numbers. $\mathbb{N}^3$ is the set of ordered (meaning one knows what the first, second, third component is) triples of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that $f$ takes ordered triples of natural numbers as inputs and for each of these triples produces a natural number as output. An example of such a function is

$$f:\Bbb N^3\to\Bbb N:\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle\mapsto x_1x_2+x_3\;,$$

or in possibly more familiar notation, the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2+x_3$, so that for instance $f$ takes $\langle 2,3,4\rangle$ to $2\cdot3+4=10$.

Comment: Thanks. Accept in a minute. I have also seen this notation in linear algebra for dimensions (not for N), but that made even less sense than the cube root. This makes more sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @skynorth: You’re welcome.